# Using phonegap app as alternative entry point for existing blackberry app?

Tags: blackberry, cordova

I have an existing blackberry app that has 2 modules. A background service and a screen that comes up when a call is made. At the moment there is no icon on the home screen.

I want to create a phonegap app and make it the app that opens when the icon is pressed on the home screen. So the installation package would consist of 3 modules. A background service, a single screen and a phonegap app.

is this possible?

thanks for your help!

Comment: You want to create an app that runs in the background + giving a screen when establishing a phoneCall + having an icon displayed on the home screen to launch the app? That is ur question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is.

When you specify an alternative entry point you may also specify an icon and an application argument. The application argument will allow you to distinguish which of your modules is being launched and the icon will be placed in your phones download folder.

If you are using eclipse these options are both listed to the right of where you specified your entry point.

Assuming the entry point argument name you choose is "phonegap" your main might look something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    if( args.length > 0 && args[ 0 ].equals( "phonegap" ) )
    {
```